# Animate the height of SVG graph bars

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, jquery-animate

**PROBLEM:**

I am trying to animate the height of SVG graph bars: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/pRTBt/

Part of my problem is that `.height()` returns `0`, yet `.attr("height")` returns the true height.

```
$(function(){
var $theBars = $("#v-bars").children();
var BarsHeight = $theBars.each(function(index, element ) {
    var origHeight = $(this).attr("height");
    console.log( index + ": " + $(this).attr("height"));
    console.log( index + ": " + $(this).height());
});
});
```

I was planning on setting the height to zero and animating the height using `jquery.animate` when `eventHander` is triggerd, but don't seem to be able to because of the returned height issue.

**QUESTION:**

1. Why is `.height()` returning zero?
2. What would be the best way to apply the original heights back to bars when, clicked for instance?

**EDIT: Part solution** http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/pRTBt/12/

It is possible to edit the height attribute. This need to figure out how to pass it the array of values

Answer (score 2):

In HTML height and width are CSS properties i.e. you might write `<div style="height:100%;height:100%">` and the height() would then be 100%. In SVG height and width are XML attributes so you write `<rect height="100%" width="100%">`

attr() gets the attribute value so that's why it works.

You could store the original values as custom attributes, the convention is to start such things with [data-](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml) and then apply the custom attribute value back to the bar when clicked.

Comment: Thx! I'll take a look at that approach. So XML elements don't have a height or width property! And they only honor height or width attributes!

Comment: The creators of SVG decided that width/height would be attributes, the creators of HTML went for CSS styles. It's not really connected with XML.